# How to downgrade Xcode to previous version?

Tags: xcode, uninstallation, downgrade

I have to use Xcode occasionally, and have now come across a problem where I've upgraded to Xcode 4.6, but another piece of software I'm using doesn't support it, so I need to go back to Xcode 4.5.

I'm not used to the way Macs work in general, so if the answers provided could be written with that in mind, that'd be helpful. :)

Answer (score 264, accepted):

I'm assuming you are having at least OSX 10.7, so go ahead into the applications folder (Click on Finder icon > On the Sidebar, you'll find "Applications", click on it ), delete the "Xcode" icon. That will remove Xcode from your system completely. Restart your mac.

Now go to [Xcode Releases page](https://xcodereleases.com) or [Apple Developer More Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and download **an older
version of Xcode**, as needed and install. You need an Apple ID to login to that portal.

After install, you can also switch between multiple versions:

Xcode > Settings > Locations > Command Line Tools

[image: Xcode switch versions]

Comment: When I go to the link I only can find xcode 3 and older, but what I need is xcode 4.6.1. Where is it? (I hate macs!)

Comment: Just letting anyone know that this still works perfectly for newer versions of Xcode (Xcode7...)

Comment: ... And now XCode 8, almost exactly a year later.

Comment: For some reason trying to move Xcode.app to trash didn't do anything. I could anyway replace the file so now I have 8.2 again. I also installed the command line tools for 8.2 just in case.

Comment: I have come from the future to confirm that this also works with Xcode 9.

Comment: I am about to remove 10.2 to install 10.1 but... is there a way to store the 10.2 so when I remove 10.1 I will be able to install without download it again?

Comment: And I'm afraid that I'm also from the future. Uninstalling 10.3 so that I can reinstall 10.2.1.

Comment: Another way to delete Xcode: _App Store_, Xcode, click on the 3 ellipses next and select _Delete_ from the menu.

Comment: Hi folks. From the future. Don't come here, the world's a mess. But at least, I could uninstall Xcode 13.3 so I was able to reinstall 13.2.1. Just wanted to let y'all know :)

Comment: Is switching the Comand Line Tools version enough to build app under that version or I should actually install it?
I mean if I have 2 apps one of those should be build at xCode12 and another one at xCode13, should I reinstall corresponding xCode version or it is enough to switch the CLT version?

Comment: This technique does not appear to work in XCode 14 going to XCode 13.4.1.  There selection does not appear in the command line tools

Comment: In 2024, the download link is: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Answer (score 16):

When you log in to your developer account, you can find a link at the bottom of the download section for Xcode that says ["Looking for an older version of Xcode?"](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode).  In there you can find download links to older versions of Xcode and other developer tools

Comment: So I don't need to uninstall 4.6, I can simply install 4.5 *as* *well*?

Comment: You can install both at the same time, but it can lead to confusion as to which version you are opening. I've had the experience before.