# Downgrade Xcode 5 to Xcode 4.6.1

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode5

I have been trying to research a way that I would be able to revert back to Xcode 4.6.1, I can't seem to find a solution.

I've seen that in the past people have downgraded their Xcode.

Is there a way that I can downgrade Xcode 5 back to Xcode 4.6.1?

I have older versions of apps which clients do not wish to upgrade. However I still need to make amendments to theses applications. I need them to remain the same.

Is there any way that I can downgrade Xcode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to downgrade Xcode to previous version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756026/how-to-downgrade-xcode-to-previous-version)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move Xcode 5 to the Trash. Download and install Xcode 4.6. You can download older versions of Xcode from the following URL:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

You can also have both Xcode 4 and 5 installed. You will have to rename your existing Xcode 5 app from Xcode to another name like Xcode5 before you install Xcode 4.6 in the Applications folder.

Comment: we can rename the xcode 5 to some name and if we install new xcode 4.6 by this way we can have two xcodes in the same system.

Comment: Is your comment a question? If so, the answer to your question is Yes. You can have multiple versions of Xcode installed on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your instruction to downgrade xcode 5.1 to xcode 4.6.1.  The steps seems to work, however, when I try to install the command line tool, the Components tab of the Downloads preferences panel shows "No components are available".  How do I get the command line tool to show up in the component panel?

Before the downgrade, with xcode 5.1, I did "xcode-select —install" to install command line tool.  I assume it has been removed when I dragged the xcode 5.1 to the trash.

Comment: Are you referring to my answer? If so, I don't have a solution for installing the command line tools. My answer only covers Xcode, not the command line tools. You should search this site for any questions on installing the command line tools. If you don't find a suitable question, ask a new question.