# How to downgrade xcodebuild?

Tags: xcodebuild, downgrade

My current project is incompatible with xcodebuild 5.1 so I'm trying to downgrade xcodebuild from 5.1 to 5.0 on my MBP with Mavericks 10.9.1. But I can't find a solution.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756026/how-to-downgrade-xcode-to-previous-version

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/downloads had XCode 5.0.2 dmg. After installing it, I'm back to xcodebuild 5.0.

Annoyingly Maverick's App Store default setting was set to automatic downloading and installing.