# Compile Error on Xcode 5.1

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction

I'm getting a unique error when compiling on Xcode lately.  The app in question is one I got from github called sios.  The error is:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mstructure-size-boundary=32' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
clang: error: unknown argument: '-falign-loops' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
clang: error: unknown argument: '-falign-labels' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
clang: error: unknown argument: '-falign-jumps' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fpeel-loops' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to talk to the people who develop that code. Those are unknown build arguments, and Xcode 5.1 contains a new version of clang that rejects them (instead of just letting them pass unnoticed, which is what happened previously).

Alternatively, compile with Xcode 5.0. (See my discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563632/341994) about how Xcode 5.0 and 5.1 can live side by side.)

Comment: I had seen some posts about the wunused post and being able to somehow keep that from throwing errors.  But, the posts I saw didn't really say how you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "unknown" arguments listed in the errors thrown by clang, from the SNES_CFLAGS under the build settings in xcode.  It will compile successfully then ;-)