# How can I downgrade Xcode from version 7.0 to 6.4?

Tags: xcode, downgrade

How can I downgrade Xcode from version 7.0 to 6.4?

I have recently upgraded the version of Xcode to the latest one (7.0) and I start having corresponding compilation errors. I want to come back to 6.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to downgrade Xcode to previous version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756026/how-to-downgrade-xcode-to-previous-version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download Xcode 6.4 from here: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.4/Xcode_6.4.dmg

Answer (score 4):

You can download the 6.4 version and install it alongside Xcode 7. Just give the 6.4 app version a new name.

Comment: Good to know, that I have few versions of them

Comment: How about command line tools and similar? If I remember, they are downlaoded via terminal. Can you also have two set of comand line tools?

Comment: You can download them from inside XCode if I remember correctly.

Comment: A couple of things with using two different versions of XCode: 1) Don't put spaces in the application name (eg, use 'Xcode6.app'): I've run into issues using custom shell scripts to configure libraries where spaces don't get escaped properly.  2) You can't have two sets of command line tools, but you shouldn't need them.  The Xcode command line tools are just that: tools for the command line.  Recent versions of Xcode use their own compilers, which are kept in the application package.