# Restore Xcode 7.3.1 after Xcode 8 upgrade

Tags: xcode, xcode8, xcode7.3

Last night I went into my Application directory and renamed the Xcode.app to Xcode7.app

I then upgraded to Xcode 8 overnight.

When I came back in the morning, Xcode7.app was gone!! Nowhere to be found.

Now my project doesn't work on Xcode 8, upgrading to Swift 3.0 is impossible as many of my dependencies don't support it yet - and upgrading to swift 2.3 also doesn't work for some reason.

What happened to my Xcode 7 ? How do I get it back now?

Comment: Just download from developer.apple.com again. It is possible you didn't quite hit return when you've changed the name. I've done that before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did. This really sucks!!!!

Comment: Takes forever to download Xcode - and then it gets stuck in the middle of the download and doesn't recover. Already tried downloading it three times. arrhhhhh!

Comment: Apple really sucks with the terrible download speed. It's 2016, not 2006.

Comment: So the solution is reinstalling, right? here's a good link reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14756127/1736679

Answer (score 2):

I did not have this problem, and I also renamed Xcode (to Xcode-7.app) before updating.

I'm guessing it's because rather than choosing 'update' from the app store, I went to apple's downloads page and downloaded from there.

Try renaming your new Xcode to Xcode8.app, then go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and download Xcode 7.3.1.dmg.

Comment: No way for me to verify right now - takes forever to download that Xcode 7.3.1.dmg - will update this post later, thanks! Yes I did "update" - will know NOT to do that next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this program:

https://github.com/KrauseFx/xcode-install

This program lets you install any Xcode version.

```
$ gem install xcode-install
$ xcversion list --all

...
7.0.1
7.1
7.1.1
7.2
7.2.1
7.3
7.3.1
8

$ xcversion install 7.3.1
```

Comment: Thanks @LaStrada, before I try this - will it override the current XCode installation?

Comment: @etayluz: No! My Xcode versions after running this:
`Xcode-8.app
Xcode.app`

Comment: If you need to urgently move back to Xcode7/Swift 2 because you use old pods, this solution is perfect!

Comment: @LaStrada, I tried this but I got this error right after entering my username and password: http.rb:921:in `connect': Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)