# Can I downgrade Xcode 8 back to Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, macos, downgrade

I have been working on a project using Xcode recently, and I looked up instructions on a website, but the code was only for Xcode 7.1, and I only have Xcode 8! I followed the steps instructed on the website but there were way too many errors! Is there a way to downgrade Xcode without using the apple website or deleted the current Xcode I have now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to downgrade Xcode to previous version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756026/how-to-downgrade-xcode-to-previous-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download both Xcode 8 and Xcode 7 into your computer. But you can't downgrade it.

You try download it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)