# How to fix this issue "framework not found GRPCClient, linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) "?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, grpc

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDKMj.png)When update the xcode 10.1 after run my project its show "Not found this framework" but the framework is there. so many time remove and add this framework but nor working.

[image: Image attachment 1]

[image: Image attachment 2]

Comment: I tried all solutions but still this issue not fixed.

Comment: Downgrade Xcode maybe?

Comment: Have you added it to Linked Frameworks and Libraries  & Embbeded binaries and also check in Build Phase -> Link Binary With Libraries it is showing or not

Comment: yes its showing in Link Binary !

Comment: @VahidAmiri How to do that ?

Comment: @SharonDRose https://stackoverflow.com/a/14756127/5173926

Comment: @VahidAmiri any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

pod deintegrate and install pods again this may work for you

pod deintegrate
delete pod file in Your Project
pod init
add your Frameworks
and pod install

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I worked from the project instead of the workspace. Once I was in the XCWorkSpace, all was good