ionic - ios - ScanDependencias command failed while building
I'm trying to build my Ionic / Cordova app but getting this error:
The following build commands failed:
  ScanDependencies /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gcpsxwgciwwqcxghqjubozbsahac/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/myapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirebasePlugin.o /Users/myuser/dev/myapp-ionic/platforms/ios/myapp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebasex/FirebasePlugin.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'myapp' from project 'myapp')
  Building workspace MyApp with scheme MyApp and configuration Release
(2 failures)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

I found no references with ScanDependencies errors, so I'm quite lost on that.
What I tried so far:

Clear DerivedData folder
Clear plugins folder
Clear node_modules folder
Clear www folder
Reinstall gems
Remove and add ios platform

Always getting to the same problem.
Any idea on how to better investigate this error?
I'm using Mac M1 with MacOS Sequoia and Xcode 16.

it states that the issue is with cordova-plugin-firebasex. make sure to update it.

I got a ScanDependencies error while trying to compile C code on Xcode 16. I don't know what ScanDependencies is, but the problem went away when I downgraded to Xcode 15. Downgrade link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756026/how-to-downgrade-xcode-to-previous-version

@KenShirriff I've added an answer here with steps to build on Xcode 16. Hope it helps someway.

I finally got it working on Xcode 16. Here is some guidance.
Clean up and reinstall iOS platform
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf plugins
rm -rf www
npm i
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add ios@^6.3.0
ionic cordova prepare ios

sudo rm -rf /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

Update post_install code block at platforms/ios/Podfile 
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      config.build_settings['ONLYARCHIVEARCH'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf'
      config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end

Reinstall Pods
cd platforms/ios && pod deintegrate && pod install && cd ../../

Prepare Ionic project
ionic cordova prepare ios

Open .xcworkspace with Xcode 16

Add arm64 to Exclude Architectures
Mark YES to Build Active Architecture Only (Debug)
Select any Simulator with Rosetta (google it on how to enable rosetta simulators on xcode 16)
Run Product -> Build

Go back to Terminal and build ionic
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release --aot

